# hit the target probability question

Tags: probability

An archer hit the target with probability 0.8. If she takes 10 shots find the probability that
she misses 2 or more

'or more' is confusing me here

Comment: What have you attempted towards solving the question? Please show it. Please edit your post to include it.

Comment: "2 or more" means NOT zero nor one.

Comment: It just means add up the probabilities that she misses $2,3,4,\ldots 10$.  It is less work to compute the chance she misses $0$ or $1$ and subtract.

Comment: "2 or more" means "at least two".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic distribution is binomial.  Let $P$ be the probability of two or more misses, then $P=\sum_{k=2}^{10} \binom{10}{k} (0.2)^k(0.8)^{10-k}$.

For calculation $1-P=(0.8)^{10}+10(0.2)(0.8)^9=0.37581$, so $P=.62419$.

Comment: when using binomial distribution formula, i get 1-P = 0.6241903616. Is there a chance you could do the calculations out a bit more so i can see where im going wrong?

Comment: My error!  I was never very good at arithmetic.  It's corrected and agrees with yours.